# Comparison of good vs bad dataset using R

Tags: r, dataset, comparison

Stuck in a problem. There are two datasets A and B. Say they're datasets of two factories. Factory A is performing really well whereas Factory B is not. I have the data-set of Factory A (data being output from the manufacturing units) as well as Factory B, both having the same variables. How can I identify the problematic variable in Factory B which needs to be fixed so that Factory B starts performing well too? Therefore, I need to identify the problematic variable which needs immediate attention.

Looking forward to your response.

p.s: coding language being used is R

Answer (score 1):

Well this is shameless plug for the [`dataMaid`](https://github.com/ekstroem/dataMaid) package which I helped write and which sort of does what you are asking. The idea of the `dataMaid` package is to run a battery of tests on the variables in a data frame and produce a report that a human investigator (preferably someone with knowledge about the context) can look through in order to identify potential problems.

A super simple way to get started is to load the package and use the
`clean` function on a data frame (if you try to clean the same data
frame several times then it may be necessary to add the `replace=TRUE`
argument to overwrite the existing report).

```
devtools::install_github("ekstroem/dataMaid")
library(dataMaid)
data(trees)
clean(trees)
```

This will create a report with summaries and error checks for each
variable in the `trees` data frame. A summary of all the variables is provided and for the `trees` data it looks like this

[image]

while the information from each variable may look like this

[image]

Here we get a status about the variable type, summary statistics, a plot and - in this case - an indicator that there might be a problem with outliers.

The `dataMaid` package can also be used interactively by running checks for the individual variables or for all variables in the dataset

```
data(toyData)
check(toyData$var2)  # Individual check of var2
check(toyData)       # Check all variables at once
```

By default the standard battery of tests is run depending on the
variable type, but it is possible to extend the package by providing your own checks.

In your case I would run the package on both datasets to get two reports, and any major differences in those would raise a flag about what could be problematic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this but it doesn't fulfill my requirements. Since I'm making a user interface for a comparison of datasets for business users, I need to show them a simple output saying "Variable X is problematic. Please rectify it" The whole processing will be done at the back-end and won't be shown to the user.

Comment: The PDF this outputs is quite useful but only for data scientists/analysts like us who can read the document and infer what's wrong.

Comment: Appreciate your help though. Thanks again. Didn't know about this library before. Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Well you can use the information provided by the package to make your own list - it is not necessary to render the results into the standard output file. Look at the `check` functions.